# Is there a WebView onReceivedError equivalent for GeckoView?

Tags: android, firefox, webview, geckoview

When using `WebView` I can handle errors with `onReceivedError` and `onReceivedHttpError`. How do I do this with `GeckoView`?

Searched through [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/package-summary.html), I expected to find a similar method for `GeckoSession` but I can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. This can be done by overriding [GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.onLoadError](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.html).

See [WebResponse](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/WebResponse.html) for HTTP error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just set NavigationDelegate to your Gecko Session.

```
 geckoSession.setNavigationDelegate(new GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public GeckoResult<String> onLoadError(@NonNull GeckoSession session, @Nullable String uri, @NonNull WebRequestError error) {
                return GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.super.onLoadError(session, uri, error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).